# How to convert String to date in Presto SQL engine?

Tags: sql, presto

I currently have dates as strings in the format

```
Fri Jun 12 2020 16:24:47 GMT-0700 (PDT).
```

I'm trying to use CAST(datestring as date), but it doesn't work. I want to be able to convert string to date so I can use `date_trunc` method.

How can I convert these Strings to dates?

Answer (score 2):

Use `select date_parse(date_string, format)` to parse the date string to date.

Here is presto [documentation for date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse)